# Java string replace issue with characters like (, ),?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to write a program where I am reading a file and replacing some text of the file with some other text. I am using `String.replaceAll` method for this purpose. The string to be replaced is being read from a .txt file.

Now, for normal string, without any special characters, everything works fine. If the string to be replaced is like:

**If yes, when?**

OR

**The value is incorrect (should be between 0-18)**

Then, the replacement of this string does not happen. I guess it is due to **?** characterm and **()** being used here as a regex. I wish it to be used a normal string and not as a regex.

Comment: Show the code you're using.

Comment: You can always escape characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions using a back slash, e.g. `\(` instead of `(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use regular expressions, it is always preferred to use [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `String.replaceAll()`, since you get rid of all the regular expression overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.replace()`, not `String.replaceAll()`!

`replaceAll()` uses *regex* for its search, and those characters you're having problems with have a special meaning in regex.

`replace()` uses plain text for its search, but still replaces all occurrences of the target.

This is a common mistake, and shows that these methods are poorly named to cause such confusion.